# Search and insert a link

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to find a word and replace it with a link. So for example:

```
<root>
<description>
Uniquely cultivate optimal supply chains before multidisciplinary infrastructures.
</description>
</root>
```

In the xsl, I'm trying to search a particular word and replace that word with a link. For example I want to replace the word "cultivate" with [cultivate](http://google.com) so the final output on the page will be:

```
 Uniquely <a href="http://google.com">cultivate</a> optimal supply chains before multidisciplinary infrastructures.
```

I'm approaching this problem using replace function like:

```
<xsl:variable name="description" select="description" />
```

and then

```
 replace($description, "(.*)(cultivate.*)", "$1test$2")
```

This just adds the word test before cultivate. I would really appreciate any help.

--UPDATE--
I was able to fix this issue using replace like this

```
<xsl:variable name="description" select="description" />
Description: <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="replace($description, '(.*)(cultivate)(.*)', '$1&lt;a href=http://google.com &gt;cultivate&lt;/a&gt;$3')" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `analyze-string` http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#regex-examples e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="description">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="cultivate">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <a href="http://example.com">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </a>
   </xsl:matching-substring>
   <xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:non-matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. Now if I want to add one more link in the same sentence like for example add a link to the word "supply"?

Comment: Well you put an alternative in the regular expression pattern e.g. `<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="cultivate|supply">...</xsl:analyze-string>`. Or you can put in another `analyze-string` into the `non-matching-substring` part to further process the for non matching input for other patterns.